# while loop for loop python

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

Consider a famous movie line by Liam Neeson. You need to print only those words from this famous line whose length is greater than 3. Also the output words should be unique.You need to take care of the special characters such as ,. Characters such as apostrophe will be considered to be part of the word.

Comment: Can you show us what did you try so far and what problems do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.